# Error building Selenium+Maven: missing pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, testing, selenium, pom.xml

I am new to Selenium and Maven tools. Trying to set up the Selenium 2.0 Java project using Maven, via [this guide](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#java).

After creating and saving pom.xml in my project directory, I run `mvn clean install` and get the following error:

`(...)
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Users\User\Documents\TestAutomation). Please verify you invoked Maven from the
 correct directory. -> [Help 1]`

My pom.xml looks like this, as in the example from the link:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>MySel20Proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>MySel20Proj</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.45.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>`

I have Maven 3.3.1 and Java 1.8.0 installed on Windows 7.

Any idea, what am I doing wrong? I have little experience with testing tools in general.

Comment: In what directory is the pom file saved to?

Comment: It's saved in `C:\Users\User\Documents\TestAutomation`, just an empty directory (with pom.xml) where I wanted Maven to create the project for me.

Comment: Can you try `mvn -f  clean install pom.xml`

Comment: It gives me the following error message: "Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: Non-readable POM ... (couldn't find the file)"

Comment: Hmmm...what compiler are you using?

Comment: Oh, I think I found what's wrong. The file is actually saved as `pom.xml.txt`, thanks to Notepad :(

Comment: Hah I was gonna ask what format it was saved in to lol

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was with the file extension. It was actually saved as `pom.xml.txt`, not `pom.xml` as I expected. (found that via `dir` command)